# File.mkdirs() returns false

Tags: android, file

I'm creating an social media platform where photos that are already on the device can be uploaded to the platform. I found a sample on github that (in theory) should enable me to read all the jpg/png files and show them in a recyclerview. The code to obtain the files is shown below.

```
private void createImageGallery() {
        File storageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        mGalleryFolder = new File(storageDirectory, GALLERY_LOCATION);
        Log.i("gallery", "" + (mGalleryFolder != null));
        Log.i("gallery", mGalleryFolder.toString());
        if (!mGalleryFolder.exists()) {
            boolean mk = mGalleryFolder.mkdirs();
            Log.i("gallery", "mkdirs returns " + mk);
        }
    }
```

The first log statement equates to true, the second shows the string

`"/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/hilarity_image"`

the third log statement says the boolean mk is false. The File object mGalleryFolder is then passed into the constructor for a recyclerview adapter. The error is thrown when adapter.getItemCount() is called. Code is shown below

```
public int getItemCount() {
        return mGalleryFolder.listFiles().length;
    }
```

The some of the permissions from the manifest are shown below

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

Apparently, .length() is being called on a null object. I assumed this had something to do with mkdirs() returning false. Is this assumption correct? How do I make it so mkdirs() returns true? Remember, the desired result is showing all the photos that are already on the device in a recyclerview, if my approach to this problem is incorrect, please correct me.

Comment: Are you asking for WRITE permissions? https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory is not created. So you should not continue with your code but stop.

Now you try to list the files in a directory that does not exist. No wonder that listFiles returns null then.

For Android 6+ you need to add code to ask the user to confirm the permissions you request in manifest.

Google for runtime permissions.

After adding the code you can create that directory.

Comment: thank you, I'll make sure to keep this in mind from now on.